# Нужна помощь в скачивании пакета NPM и его подключении к CSS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, cmd, npm

Уважаемые программисты, здравствуйте!

У меня возникла следующая проблема: я хочу **использовать CSS-переменные в качестве условий для *медиа-запросов***, но `CSS` **запрещает** мне это делать (просто игнорирует *медиа-запросы*).

Почитав форумов я заметил, что все пишут про пакет `NPM` под названием `postcss-media-variables`, который якобы должен позволять мне использовать мои переменные в этих *медиа-запросах*.

Почитав немного про `NPM`, посмотрев гайды и туториалы, я понял только то, что ты пишешь команды в специальную консоль и тебе устанавливаются нужные тебе пакеты.

Я попробовал, но у меня **глобально** нужный пакет установился:

[image: Установленные глобально пакеты]

А при установке **локально**, в нужную мне директорию, выдало кучу предупреждений и ничего так и **не установило**:

[image: Установка пакета локально]

Хотя у человека на видео, всё получилось.

Я в этом деле абсолютно чайник, так что если я где-то ошибся - не надо кидать в меня помидорами.

Очень хочется узнать про **установку** этого пакета.

Буду рад любой помощи!

### Заранее спасибо!

Скачал gulp, gulp-postcss, postcss-media-variables написал gulpfile.js:

```js
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var postcssmediavariables = require('postcss-media-variables');

gulp.task('serve', ['css'], function() { 
    gulp.watch("./css/*.css", ['css'])
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
    var plugin = [
        postcssmediavariables()
    ];
    return gulp.src('./css/*.css')
        .pipe(postcss(plugin))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

```css
:root {
  --size: 500px;
}

.b1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: var(--size)) {
  .b1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Yan Gordon</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <meta name="yandex-verification" content="f356f6cc893787fc">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="b1"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

На выходе:

```
C:\Users\Колба\Колба\YanGordon>gulp
assert.js:350
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\Колба\Колба\YanGordon\node_modules\under
taker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\Колба\Колба\YanGordon\node_modules\undertaker\lib\tas
k.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Колба\Колба\YanGordon\gulpfile.js:5:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)

C:\Users\Колба\Колба\YanGordon>
```

Что делать?

Comment: как вы определили, что локально ничего не установило?

Comment: @Дмытрык , здравствуйте! В папке куда я устанавливал ничего не появилось, она как и была пустой так и осталась.

Comment: В вашей папке есть package.json?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, она полностью пустая

Comment: покажите скрин папки

Comment: да и вообще... если пакет установлен глобально, то смысла нет, иметь его физическое нахождение - локально. Достаточно, чтобы он был в зависимостях.

Comment: @Дмытрык не знаю есть ли какая-то связь, но у меня когда я пытался установить в C:\Users\...\... у меня не получалось без фаила package, а в C:\... получилось и с файлом package и без.

Comment: версия npm какая?

Comment: Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 10.15.3 (ia32) and npm.

Comment: на команду `npm -v` должно показать, что-то типа такого `6.9.0`

Comment: @Дмытрык 6.4.1 показывает

Comment: @Дмытрык почитайте в коментариях под ответом ниже я написал что у меня всё установилось хорошо

Comment: @Дмытрык мне нужна помощь с подключением к CSS

Comment: я никогда его не подключал, но в примере, вроде все очевидно https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-media-variables#example-1  ... он не "подключается" к CSS, а создает новый, понятный для брузеров

Answer (score 1):

1. Сначала необнодимо создать файл [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json):

---

```
{
  "name": "app name",
  "description": "app description",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

это можно сделать либо созданием его вручную, однако есть встроенный спороб:

> `npm init`

после нескольких капитанских вопосов, на которые везде можно нажать enter появится `packaje.json`

2. Теперь можно устанавливать npm зависимости:

> `npm i postcss-media-variables`

Comment: А как подключить к CSS этот пакет?

Comment: пакеты должны устанавливаются автоматически в даже в пустой папке. Я проверял.

Comment: @Дмытрык может быть в последних версиях npm, но раньше так не было :)

Comment: @SlavaEpifanov он установился?

Comment: там на скрине видно, что пакет добавлен.... стоит + . И написано, что 1 пакет обновлен.

Comment: У меня всё установилось куда нужно, локально, есть package.json, есть package-lock.json и есть папочка node_modules с пакетом, как я понимаю, так что на этом этапе всё отлично! Теперь мне надо разобраться с подключением в CSS этого пакета

Comment: @SlavaEpifanov это плагин для сборщика, как его использовать можно посмотреть вот тут https://github.com/WolfgangKluge/postcss-media-variables

Comment: @StrangerintheQ извините, я ничего не понял на этом сайте - я натыкался на него читал эту документацию но ничего не понял. Там что то скачивать надо?

Comment: @SlavaEpifanov этот пакет, запускается препроцессором, например gulp, он делает из одного кода другой, а конкретно этот пакет как-то работает с переменными и медиа запросами, но я им никогда не пользовался

Comment: @StrangerintheQ этот препроцессор надо тоже локально установить в директорию моего проекта, а потом что?

Comment: @SlavaEpifanov это Gulp, он может быть и глобально установлен или локально не важно, глобальный проще запускать он виден во всей стстеме

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я вообще в принципе не понимаю что надо делать, что создавать, что прописывать чтобы этот пакет подключился наконец

Comment: @SlavaEpifanov это не пакет для подключения, это расширение, которое позволит вам использовать синтаксис которого нет с стандарте и что-то, и потом этот плагин сделает из него рабочий код

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я пересмотрел, перепробовал всё что только можно написал код(ща покажу в ответе)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я написал всё в ответе